# Array extension for finding index of custom type

Tags: arrays, swift

How would I write an extension for `Array` to find the index of a value of a specific type?

I want the method to behave the same as the `index(of: Element)` call.

So far:

```
extension Array {
    func index(of fruit: Fruit) -> Int {
        for item in self {
            if item == fruit {
            //return the number 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use the existing `index(of:)` (or `index(where:)`) method?

Comment: How does your function differ from the existing `index(of:)`? If you want to see how it's implemented, the source is on github: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/5afeecb246fb4772f357766d395a79585000201b/stdlib/public/core/CollectionAlgorithms.swift#L57-L71

Comment: @RobNapier the function doesn't differ. I guess what I'm confused about is that I cant just use the .index(of: ) method call on an array of Fruit. The Fruit class does not conform to equatable. Do I need to make it conform?

Comment: @leedex if you are not searching for an specific instance of the Fruit you don't need to conform to Equatable. If you are just searching for specific type in your array check my post below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend Array and create a generic method to return the first index where the element is of an specific type:

```
extension Array {
    func index<T>(with type: T.Type) -> Index? {
        return index { $0 is T }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Fruit { }

let objects: [Any] = [1,2,Fruit(),"leedex"]
objects.index(with: Fruit.self)   // 2
```

Comment: No need for the extension. Just use `objects.index(where: { $0 is Fruit })`.

Comment: @rmaddy obbvious and even simpler `objects.index { $0 is Fruit }` but the question is how to create an extension

Comment: True but the OP probably didn't realize how simple it was to get the index.

Comment: You guys are awesome. Thank you.